# Synchronize not all folders with skydrive

Tags: windows-7, sync, onedrive

For example i have home and work computers with skydrive installed on both. What i want is to add everything i need to skydrive at home, but only download several folders at work. For example i have music and books folders at home, but want just books at work. Is it possible(planned) with skydrive for desktop?

Answer (score 1):

SkyDrive is young and other similar services do have selective folder synchronization so it may or may not get added to SkyDrive in the near or distant future.

I would suggest accessing SkyDrive through the web interface while at work at not the desktop software while you wait.

Comment: Nice idea..But using web interface i cant find anything..It only searches Office files in my documents folder. Doesnt even show PDF file that is located there too. Without good search i nearly cant use web interface.

Comment: Same answer, Skydrive is young and other services have more comprehensive search (Google Drive / Docs for example searchs PDFs and even does some OCR) that might eventually be added to SkyDrive.